# Use CSS to Get Multiple, Proportionate Images Side By Side In Twitter-Bootstrap Row With 100% Width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have 7 images that I'm trying to display horizontally within a row. I'm using bootstrap to write this. What I'm trying to achieve should look like this:

[image]

When the page gets resized, these images should stay proportionate to one another, until eventually at mobile (425px and below), when they should collapse into 1-column rows.

[image]

What I've tried so far looks like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="row thumbnail-row">

<div>
<img class="thumbnail-image" src="/wp-content/themes/gatewaywebdesign/assets/images/hamburger-thumbnail.jpg"/>
</div>

<div>
<img class="thumbnail-image" src="/wp-content/themes/gatewaywebdesign/assets/images/yoyomoi-thumbnail.jpg"/>
</div>

<div>
<img class="thumbnail-image" src="/wp-content/themes/gatewaywebdesign/assets/images/dogs-thumbnail.jpg"/>
</div>

<div>
<img class="thumbnail-image" src="/wp-content/themes/gatewaywebdesign/assets/images/gateway-thumbnail.jpg"/>
</div>

<div>
<img class="thumbnail-image" src="/wp-content/themes/gatewaywebdesign/assets/images/chameleon-thumbnail.jpg"/>
</div>

<div>
<img class="thumbnail-image" src="/wp-content/themes/gatewaywebdesign/assets/images/adrienne-thumbnail.jpg"/>
</div>

<div>
<img class="thumbnail-image" src="/wp-content/themes/gatewaywebdesign/assets/images/castaway-thumbnail.jpg"/>
</div>

</div><!--end row-->
```

CSS:

```
.thumbnail-row {
display: flex;
}

.thumbnail-image {
display: inline-block;
/*width: 14.286%;*/
/*height: 50px;*/
}
```

When I do this, it does get the images next to each other, but they're way too wide and they don't fit the width of the page/window.

See this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vo1npqdx/1259/).

Also tried this:

CSS:

```
.thumbnail-row {
display: flex;
overflow: hidden;
}

.thumbnail-image {
width: 14.286%;
float: left;
}
```

But that didn't work either. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `max-width: 100%` to the images and they'll display in a horizontal row. Without that, they're overflowing the parent. Then you can use `col-*` classes to reorganize into a column at a breakpoint, or just use a `@media` query and switch the `flex-direction`

```css
.thumbnail-row {
  display: flex;
}

.thumbnail-image {
  display: inline-block;
  /*width: 14.286%;*/
  /*height: 50px;*/
  max-width: 100%;
}

@media (max-width: 425px) {
  .thumbnail-row {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">

  <div class="row thumbnail-row">
    <div>
      <img class="thumbnail-image" src="http://i.imgur.com/mNoKbYK.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <img class="thumbnail-image" src="http://i.imgur.com/8b2sb03.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <img class="thumbnail-image" src="http://i.imgur.com/Ac11pRH.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <img class="thumbnail-image" src="http://i.imgur.com/DgNt5MQ.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <img class="thumbnail-image" src="http://i.imgur.com/SG0bpMU.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <img class="thumbnail-image" src="http://i.imgur.com/x1DxQwd.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <img class="thumbnail-image" src="http://i.imgur.com/YcnOqR1.jpg" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--end row-->
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah this has got it working - any suggestions for causing them to collapse at 425px and below?

Comment: It's forcing me to wait to accept your answer but it's working perfectly now - thank you.